# Python Pandas: Select Multiple Cell Values of one column based on the Value of another Column

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

So my data, in Pandas, looks like this:

```
values    variables
134       1
12        2
43        1
54        3 
16        2
```

And I want to create a new column which is the sum of `values` whenever the rest of `variables` does not equal the variable of the current row in `variables`. For example, for the first row, I would want to sum all the rows of `values` where `variables != 1`. The result would look like this:

```
values    variables   result
    134       1       82
    12        2       231
    43        1       82
    54        3       205
    16        2       231
```

I've tried a couple things like enumerate, but I can't seem to get a good handle on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of finding the sum of all values that aren't equal to the current variable, you can equivalently subtract the sum of all values that are equal to the current variable from the total sum without any filters:

```
df['result'] = df['values'].sum()
df['result'] -= df.groupby('variables')['values'].transform('sum')
```

Or in a single line if you want to be terse:

```
df['result'] = df['values'].sum() - df.groupby('variables')['values'].transform('sum')
```

The resulting output:

```
   values  variables  result
0     134          1      82
1      12          2     231
2      43          1      82
3      54          3     205
4      16          2     231
```